# How to set many functions using the same variables all at once?

Tags: python-3.x, function

I have many functions all using the same 2 variables (u,v). I am trying to find a way to be able to initialize all these functions all at once by entering the the value of (u,v) only one time instead of doing it one by one and having to enter the same value of (u,v) for every function.

I have tried to set one main function but it gives me an error message.

```
    def calcul(u,v):
        k1e=np.array([kx(u,v,R),ky(u,v,r),kz(u,v,r)])+point1
        k2e=...
        k3e=...
```

And this is the long way i am trying to avoid

```
    def k1e(u,v):
        np.array([kx(u,v,R),ky(u,v,r),kz(u,v,r)])+point1
    def k2e(u,v):
        np.array([kx(u,v,R),ky(u,v,r),kz(u,v,r)])+point2
    def k3e(u,v):
        np.array([kx(u,v,r),ky(u,v,R),kz(u,v,r)])+point3
    def k4e(u,v):
        np.array([kx(u,v,r),ky(u,v,R),kz(u,v,r)])+point4
    def k5e(u,v):
        np.array([kx(u,v,r),ky(u,v,r),kz(u,v,R)])+point5
    def k6e(u,v):
        np.array([kx(u,v,r),ky(u,v,r),kz(u,v,R)])+point6
    def k1h(u,v):
        np.array([kx(u,v,Rh),ky(u,v,rh),kz(u,v,rh)])+point1
    def k2h(u,v):
        np.array([kx(u,v,Rh),ky(u,v,rh),kz(u,v,rh)])+point2
    def k3h(u,v):
        np.array([kx(u,v,rh),ky(u,v,Rh),kz(u,v,rh)])+point3
    def k4h(u,v):
       np.array([kx(u,v,rh),ky(u,v,Rh),kz(u,v,rh)])+point4
    def k5h(u,v):
        np.array([kx(u,v,rh),ky(u,v,rh),kz(u,v,Rh)])+point5
    def k6h(u,v):
        np.array([kx(u,v,rh),ky(u,v,rh),kz(u,v,Rh)])+point6
```

Comment: *I have tried to set one main function but it gives me an error message* - and what was that error message?

Comment: At a guess, you're not really after wanting multiple functions, more just a `def calcul(u, v, point): return np.array([kx(u,v,R),ky(u,v,r),kz(u,v,r)])+point` and then just call that as `calcul(u, v, point1)` or `calcul(u, v, point5)` etc...

Comment: The error message i get is : 'local variable k1e is assigned to but never used'

Comment: Jon Clements, it would be a great idea but for every different ke1,ke2, the value of ke1=kx(u,v,something),ky(u,v,something),kz(u,v,something), the something value will not be the same form ke1, ke2 until ke6